# Why are all the non referenced paper in the bib are displayed?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using the class of `ios journal` `\documentclass[ds]{iosart2x}`. I have a central .bib file where I used across all my papers. The problem comes when in the ios template include all the papers in this bib even if they aren't referenced in this paper.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Hard to say without a code from your side. Maybe you have `\nocite{*}` somewhere.

Comment: AFAICS `iosart2x` does not use `biblatex`, but traditional BibTeX, so I removed the  `biblatex` tag. Normally BibTeX (and `biblatex`) only list cited references in the bibliography. If you have a `\nocite{*}` in your document, all entries from your `.bib` file will be added to the bibliography even if they were not cited explicitly. [`isp_template.tex`](//github.com/vtex-soft/texsupport.iospress-isp/blob/1c9053e9f3841778ed39493edc7dfc1a801bde8f/isp_template.tex#L100) has a `\nocite{*}` so if you work from that template you probably only need to remove it and run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX again

Comment: @moewe Can you add an answer?

Comment: @egreg Done....

Answer (score 2):

Normally BibTeX only lists cited references in the bibliography (it's the same for `biblatex`). With `\nocite{<key>}` one can add references to the bibliography without actually citing them. With `\nocite{*}` all entries from the `.bib` file will be added to the bibliography even if they were not cited explicitly.

And indeed if one googles for `\documentclass[ds]{iosart2x}` one of the first hits is [`ds_template.tex`](https://github.com/vtex-soft/texsupport.iospress-ds/blob/master/ds_template.tex). [That file contains a`\nocite{*}` towards the end](https://github.com/vtex-soft/texsupport.iospress-ds/blob/f7067965bc3b7247195715544e2159779d5adf26/ds_template.tex#L110), so if you are using it as a template that would explain what you are seeing.

If you don't want to see uncited references in the bibliography, remove the `\nocite{*}` and recompile your document with (at least) LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX.